# Bound on coefficients of Hasse-Weil function

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$. For $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we define $a_n$ as follows.

1. $a_1 = 1$.
2. If $n = p$,
   $$
   a_p = \begin{cases}
   p+1-|E(\mathbb{F_p})| & E \text{ has good reduction at } p\\
   0 & E \text{ has additive reduction at } p\\
   1 & E \text{ has split multiplicative reduction at } p\\
   -1 & E \text{ has non split multiplicative reduction at } p\\
   \end{cases}.
   $$
3. If $n=p^r$, for $r\ge 2$
   $$
   a_{p^r} =
   \begin{cases}
   a_p\cdot a_{p^{r-1}} - p\cdot a_{p^{r-2}} & E \text{ has good reduction at } p\\
   (a_p)^r & E \text{ has bad reduction at } p\\
   \end{cases}.
   $$
4. If $n=n_1n_2$, with $(n_1,n_2) = 1$, then $a_n = a_{n_1}\cdot a_{n_2}$.

Then the Hasse-Weil function can be written as the series
$$
L(E,s) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{a_n}{n^s}.
$$
My question relates to the Hasse bound which says $|a_p|\le 2\sqrt{p}$. Can a similar bound be extended to all $a_n$? My main obstacle is the recursive definition of $a_{p^r}$.

Comment: It is already giving the bound for all. By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, one can express a number as powers of primes. Using this representation you can find the bound by using the four property.

Comment: @kelalaka Wouldn't this require complete multiplicity of $a$? Certainly if $(a_{p^r}) = (a_p)^r$ for all $p$ then we would have $|a_n|\le 2\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: I meant you can calculate all by using the four property.

Comment: Say $E$ has good reduction at $p$. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of $x^2 - a_p x + p$, then the Hasse bounds are equivalent to the equalities $|\alpha| = |\beta| = \sqrt{p}$. However, one also finds (from the formulas given) that  $a_{p^n} = \alpha^{n} + \beta^{n}$ so $|a_{p^n}| \le 2 \sqrt{p^n}$. Then, by multiplicativity, $a_n \le 2^{\omega(n)} \sqrt{n}$, where $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$.